# Python: Equivalent to Matlab's svds(A, k) for large arrays?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to port some code from Matlab to Python and I've run into a problem. I can't seem to find an equivalent to svds.

I tried using numpy.corrcoef and then numpy.linalg.eig, but numpy.corrcoef doesn't work for large arrays (say 500 x 20000).

Here's the code in matlab, in case it makes any difference:

```
s = size(data, 2)
mean = sum(data, 2)/s
m_data = ( data - repmat(mean, 1, s) ) / sqrt(s - 1)
[res_u,res_s] = svds(m_data, s)
eigenvals = diag(res_s).^2
eigenvecs = res_u
```

Comment: Is `numpy.linalg.svd` insufficient as well?

Comment: @kwatford The problem isn't eig/svd, it's corrcoef. And in order for either eig or svd to work, I have to use corrcoef before. Well, with my current approach. There might be another way to approach it that I'm not aware.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on the `correlation coefficients`? How are they related to your `matlab`-code. See my answer, there should be no problem to add processing of `correlation coefficients`, indeed. But what is your justifaction for them? Please, show us your full `matlab'-code, with calculation of `correlation coefficients` in order to further understand what you  are aiming for! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So what you are looking for, would be something like this in `python` and `numpy` (I took the liberty not to 'directly translate' the `matlab`-code to `python` and `numpy`, instead I refactored it a little bit to 'feel' more `pythonic` [of'course quite similar refactoring can be applied to the `matlab`-code as well]):

```
import numpy as np

def _cas(D):
    """Center at mean and standardize."""
    return (D- D.mean(1)[:, None])/ (D.shape[1]- 1)** .5

def example(D):
    """Eigenvalues and -vectors, based on SVD."""
    u, s, v= np.linalg.svd(D, full_matrices= False);
    return np.diag(s)** 2, u

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data= np.random.rand(5, 20)
    data= _cas(data) # preprocess data according to your requirements
    eigenvals, eigenvecs= example(data)
    print eigenvals
    print eigenvecs
```

But you have a performance problem with it?

Can you now be more specific of your current performance, and how much you really to expect it should be enhanced?  FTIW in my modest computer, a random (500, 20000) matrix will spend executing `example(.)` some 20 secs.

I can trivially (due to basic linear algebra) reduce the execution time down to a level like 2.5 sec (allmost 10 fold improvement)! Now, if you are looking for much better performance than this, then please elaborate in much more detailed level on the 'nature' of your `data`!

Where is your data coming from? What is your specific case to utilize the calculated eigenvalues,  and -vectors? i.e. what is your main goal to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If your matrix is sparse, you can use `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` in a recent scipy distribution. It wraps the sparse SVD routine in ARPACK. In my experience, it is buggy (not sure if this is the fault of scipy or ARPACK), so I advise running tests to check that the singular values are as expected.

If your matrix is dense, 500 by 20000 is big but not intractable on a commodity desktop these days. You **are** calling `numpy.linalg.svd` with `full_matrices=False`, right?

What are you using `numpy.corrcoef` for? Nothing like that appears in the MATLAB code snippet that you posted.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a matrix for which Scipy's svds does not work correctly. Can you supply one? The source code is pretty straightforward.